# How to execute a function on first call in a recursive template function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, recursion, variadic-functions

Question title says it all, so how do you execute a function on a first call in a recursive template function?

---

I thought of using default variables in the function signature, but there isn't a place where the variable doesn't interfere with the rest of the function signature. Here's what I mean:

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
void print(T first, Ts... params) { ... }
```

*Note: I'm using a `bool` (`b`) to determine if the function wasn't called from itself.*

1. `void print(bool b = true, T first, Ts... params);`. Doesn't work if called with only 1 argument (i.e. `print("hello");`), because the compiler initializes `b` with `"hello"`.
2. `void print(T first, bool b = true, Ts... params);`. Doesn't work with multiple arguments (i.e. `print("hello", "world", "again");`), because the compiler initializes `b` with the second parameter in the parameter pack..
3. `void print(T first, Ts... params, bool b = true);`. Same as `2`, except that `b` is initialized with the last parameter in the parameter pack.

What I would like is something like this (or something else involving template arguments if you want (or something completely different))

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
void print(T first, Ts... params)
{
    if (...) // Magic!
        foo();
    std::cout << first << '\n';

    print(params...);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe have two functions? The first function does the extra call and then calls the second function that does the recursion.

Comment: @Galik I guess that would work :) Thank you

Comment: What you want to know is that is it a first time to call this function?

Comment: @Kason, not exactly. I want to call a function when the other function is first called, but the other function is recursive, hence my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to have more than one function. The outer function makes the extra call and then calles the recursive inner function(s):

```
void foo()
{
    std::cout << "foo\n";
}

// satisfy the zero-parameter case
void internal_print()
{
}

// inner recursive function    
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
void internal_print(T first, Ts... params)
{
    std::cout << first << '\n';
    internal_print(params...);
}

// outer special case function    
template<typename... Ts>
void print(Ts... params)
{
    foo();
    internal_print(params...);
}

int main()
{
    print(1, 2, "three", 4.0);
}
```

**Output:**

```
foo
1
2
three
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Could try a static variable..

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
void print(T first, Ts... params)
{
    static bool in_print = false;

    if (!in_print) // Magic!
    {
        foo();
        std::cout << first << '\n';
    }

    in_print = true;
    print(params...);
    in_print = false;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe it will help (if I understand your problem corectly):

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
void print(T first, Ts... params)
{
    static unsigned int ctr = 0;
    if (...) // Magic!
        foo();
    std::cout << first << '\n';
    ctr++;

    print(first, params...);
}
```